# Conceptual basis for formula for sum of n first integers raised to power k,

Tags: sequences-and-series

Most programmers (including me) are painfully aware of quadratic behavior resulting from a loop that internally performs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on operations per iteration,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n \left(n+1\right)}{2} $$

It’s very easy to derive, e.g. considering the double of the sum like $(1+2+3) + (3+2+1) = 3\times4$ .

For the sum of squares there is a very similar formula,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+1)}{3}$$

But the only way I found to derive that was to *assume* it would sum to a cubic polynomial $f(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$, and solve for $f(n)-f(n-1)=n^2$.

I’m guessing that there is a much simpler system and concept here, generalizing to $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^m$ a polynomial with degree $m+1$ in $n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/why-is-sum-limits-k-1n-km-a-polynomial-with-degree-m1-in-n)

Comment: @Aryabhata: thanks, but I'm more like fishing for general formula and underlying easy way to understand it (how it occurs). I'm not a matehmatician. :-)

Comment: There are multiple answers in the thread I linked. One of them talks about the [Faulhaber's formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). If you understand a bit of integral calculus, Euler Summation gives you an easy way to see the formula, and a more elementary answer is given by Derek Jennings. Perhaps you would like to edit the question to ask for clarification of one of those answers there?

Comment: There seem to be two questions here: 1) why is the sum a polynomial? 2) given that it is a polynomial, what's a conceptual way to find its coefficients? The linked question primarily addresses the first question but also addresses the second; are you more concerned about the second?

Comment: @Qiaochu: I'm mostly concerned with the second. Well I've tried to follow references and at last ended up on [Umbral Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbral_calculus) in Wikipedia, like, the Dark Side of math, and my head is spinning. I head some idea that there would be some pretty simple system, but alas, it doesn't seem to... Anyway, thanks to all here!

Comment: @Alf: yes, there are conceptual paths to writing these formulas down non-recursively but none of them are particularly easy. Of course their study is very rewarding.

Answer (score 3):

These "power sum" polynomials are known as Bernoulli polynomials, and have been studied for centuries, and there is a vast literature about them. There are many inductive formulae relating them. As you observed, the right thing to do is to consider a polynomial $f_{k}(x)$ with $f_{k}(0) = 0$
and $f_{k}(x+1) - f_{k}(x) = (x+1)^{k}$, where $k$ is a chosen positive integer.
Notice that is a polnomial of finite degree satisfies this equation for all positive integers, then it must satisfy it for all real $x$, and furthermore, it is unique.
Notice also that, given such a polynomial exists, we must have $f(-1) =0$, so that both $x$ and $x+1$ must be factors
for $f_{k}(x)$ for every $k$, given that $f_{k}$ exists. How do we know that the 
polynomial $f_{k}(x)$ always exists? There are many ways to see this. I like an inductive
approach. The polynomial $f_{1}(x) = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}$ gets us started. How can we find $f_{k+1},$ given $f_{k}$? Well, one way to do it is to notice that if we had $f_{k+1}$
and differentiated its defining equation, we would obtain
$f_{k+1}^{'}(x+1) - f_{k+1}^{'}(x) = (k+1)(x+1)^{k}$, which is nearly the defining 
equation for $f_{k}$, apart from a factor $k+1$ and the possible addition of a constant. Hence, if it is to exist, we should have $f_{k+1}(x) = c(k+1)x + d(k+1) + (k+1)\int_{-1}^{x} f_{k}(t) dt$  for certain constants $c(k+1)$ and $d(k+1)$. We can determine the constants $c(k+1)$ and $d(k+1)$.
Since we need $f_{k+1}(0) = 0$, we must have $d(k+1) = -(k+1)\int_{-1}^{0} f_{k}(t)dt$.
Since we need $f_{k+1}(-1) = 0$, we need $c(k+1) = d(k+1)$.  Hence we have uniquely
specified a polynomial $f_{k+1}$ (of degree $k+2$) with the right properties.
It is $f_{k+1}(x) = -(x+1)(k+1)\int_{-1}^{0}f_{k}(t)dt + (k+1) \int_{-1}^{x} f_{k}(t)dt$.

This can be rewritten as 
$$ \frac{f_{k+1}(x)}{k+1} = x \int_{0}^{-1}f_{k}(t)dt + \int_{0}^{x} f_{k}(t)dt$$
if preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is actually quite nice. I doubt you'll find some very conceptually simple way of computing the general formula (so that you could look at it and say: *aha! that was why...!*). There are some "visual proofs" for power [one](http://www.takayaiwamoto.com/Sums_and_Series/sumint_1.html) and [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-k-1n-k2-fracnn12n16/48152#48152) but I don't think they can be generalized.
Mathematically, for can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/why-is-sum-limits-k-1n-km-a-polynomial-with-degree-m1-in-n/18991#18991) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-k-1n-k2-fracnn12n16/48225#48225). But this, I guess,  is not what you're looking for.

Comment: I really liked [your answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-k-1n-k2-fracnn12n16/48225#48225) over at the second "here". Because it was in a sense very clean and very surprising. But you're right, I was looking for something more geometrical are numberish. :-)