# Partial Sum of a Polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, closed-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^m$ a polynomial with degree $m+1$ in $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/why-is-sum-limits-k-1n-km-a-polynomial-with-degree-m1-in-n)

I'm searching for a way to find the partial sum of a polynomial, is there any way of doing this formulaically instead of just guessing and checking?

For example...

$$\sum_{x=1}^n {x^{2}}=?$$

or...

$$\sum_{x=1}^n (4x^2+7x+2)=?$$

Comment: related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49630/conceptual-basis-for-formula-for-sum-of-n-first-integers-raised-to-power-k

Comment: http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/SumOfPowers.html

Answer (score 5):

Because of linearily, it is enough to find $S_k(n)=\sum_{x=0}^nx^k$.

This can be done with [Bernoulli polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Sums_of_pth_powers) using [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

A little computation using this information shows that, for example, $$\sum_{x=1}^N(4x^2+7x+2)=\frac{1}{6} \left(8 N^3+33 N^2+37 N\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

You can also find a formula directly. The partial sums of a polynomial function are given by a polynomial function. Since the higher-order differences of the values of a polynomial function are eventually zero, you can go backwards and find an expression for the sum in terms of [Newton polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) with coefficients the first element in each row of differences; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series.

For your example, the differences are

$0 \quad 13 \quad 45 \quad 104 \quad 198$

$13 \quad 32 \quad 59 \quad 94$

$19 \quad 27 \quad 35 $

$8 \quad 8$

$0$

and so the formula is
$$
0{n \choose 0} + 13{n \choose 1}+19{n \choose 2}+8{n \choose 3}
$$
which of course agrees with Mariano's answer.

Comment: A nice explanation is http://math.stackexchange.com/a/18990/589

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13%2C45%2C104%2C198%2C335) can also find a formula.