# Formula for  $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^p}$ where p is a positive integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^m$ a polynomial with degree $m+1$ in $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/why-is-sum-limits-k-1n-km-a-polynomial-with-degree-m1-in-n)

Any hints that can take me from here or am I completely lost.

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^p}=\sum_{a=1}^{p}(-1)^{p-a}(\sum_{b=0}^{a-1}\binom{a}{b}(a-b)^n(-1)^b)(\sum_{a1<a2<a3...<an}a1)$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^p}=\sum_{a=1}^{p}(-1)^{p-a}(\sum_{b=0}^{a-1}\binom{a}{b}(a-b)^n(-1)^b)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n+1-i)^{a-1}(i)))$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^p}=\sum_{a=1}^{p}(-1)^{p-a}(\sum_{b=0}^{a}\binom{a}{b}(a-b)^n(-1)^b)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n+1-i)^{a-1}(i)))$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^p}=\sum_{a=1}^{p}(-1)^{p-a}(a!S(n,a))(\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i)^{a-1}(n+1-i)))$

Where S(n,a) is a stirling number of second kind.

Comment: I assume $p$ is a positive integer. There is a moderately complicated [General Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for the sum, involving the Bernoulli numbers.  The term "power series" is a technical term that refers to something else.

Comment: Yes p is a positive integer. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: If you like you look at http://go.helms-net.de/math/potenzsummen/potenzsummen_1.htm which is a very old and completely elementary treatize of mine, of when I explored this myself the first time. Unfortunately in german, but I think the formulae and expressions are clear enough to hint you to a fruitful direction (for instance introducing how the Eulerian numbers of hkju's answer come into play)

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^p = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} T(p,k)\binom{n+1+k}{p+1}. \mbox{ (hence, its degree is $p+1$)}$$, where $T(p,k)$ is the Eulerian number (cf.OEIS A008292). 
For example, $p=2$:$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{1} T(2,k)\binom{n+1+k}{3}=(1)\binom{n+1}{3}+(1)\binom{n+2}{3}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
$p=3$:$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 = \sum_{k=0}^{2} T(3,k)\binom{n+1+k}{4}=(1)\binom{n+1}{4}+(4)\binom{n+2}{4}+(1)\binom{n+3}{4}=\frac{n^2 (n+1)^2}{4}$$