# How to prove that $1^r + 2^r +... + n^r = a_1 n^1 + a_2 n^2 +... + a_{r+1} n^{r+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I see this equation 
$$
1^r + 2^r +... + n^r = a_1 n^1 + a_2 n^2 +... + a_{r+1} n^{r+1}
$$ in *Introduction to Linear Algebra*, where $a_k$s are some constants.

---

How can I prove it?

Comment: what?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I wanna know how to prove this equation. can you help me?

Comment: what are those $a_k$'s?

Comment: See for example https://gowers.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/sums-of-kth-powers/ It has been asked before here, but can't find it right now

Comment: don't you need an $a_0$ also?

Comment: Where did you see this expression? In what book?

Comment: Related: [why is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^m$  a polynomial with degree $m+1$  in $n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/why-is-sum-limits-k-1n-km-a-polynomial-with-degree-m1-in-n)

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Oh man, I love that post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s^r$ can be expressed as a linear combination of ${s \choose 0},{s \choose 1},...{s \choose r}$ where the constant on ${s \choose r}$ must be non zero. Then apply the [hockey stick identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1k1) to show that the sum in question is a linear combination of ${n+1 \choose 1}, {n+1 \choose 2},....{n+1 \choose r+1}$, and again the constant on ${n+1 \choose r+1}$ is nonzero.  Thus showing that sum is a polynomial of degree $r+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Oh ok, I think I understand the question.

You want to prove that for a fixed $r$, there exists a degree $r+1$ polynomial $P$ with constant term $0$  such that $1^r+2^r+\dots+ n^r=P(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z^+$.

This has been asked several times before, my favorite solution is with combinatorics and stirling coefficients, but you can find a bunch of solutions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035188/methods-to-compute-sum-k-1nkp-without-faulhabers-formula)