# Polynomials evaluated on all subsets

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, reference-request, summation, multivariate-polynomial

Let $f(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ be a multivariate polynomial of degree $m$.
It is a seemingly well known fact that
$$
g(n) = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \dots < i_k \leq n} f(i_1,\dots,i_k)
$$
is a polynomial of degree $m+k$, though I can't find an explicit reference.
I am interested in finding a reference for this fact and the stronger statement that $g$ is divisible by $\binom{n}{k}$ (note this is the evaluation when $f=1$).
The univariate case is discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/why-is-sum-limits-k-1n-km-a-polynomial-with-degree-m1-in-n).

**Example:** Let $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 x_2$. Then
$$
g(4) = 1^22 +1^23 + 2^23+1^24+2^24+3^24 = 73.
$$
Note $g(4) - g(3) = 4 (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2)$, and more generally
$$
g(n+1) - g(n) = n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^2 = n^2(n+1)(2n+1)/6.
$$
Since the difference is a polynomial of degree $4$, we see $g(n)$ must be a polynomial of degree 5.
To compute it, we use polynomial interpolation with the values
$$
g(-1) = g(0) = g(1) = 0, g(2) = 2, g(3) = 17, g(4)=73
$$
and $g(-1) =  g(0) - (-1) \cdot (-2+1) \cdot (-1+1) = 0$.
This gives
$$
g(n) = \frac{1}{120} n(n-1)(n+1)(8n^2 +5n-2) = \binom{n}{2} \frac{(n+1)(8n^2+5n-2)}{60}.
$$

More generally, one can prove this result for monomials by induction following the outline of our example, and the rest follows by linearity.
The divisibility by $\binom{n}{k}$ follows since $0,1,\dots,k-1$ are roots of $g$.

I would like to understand the result in a more conceptual way.
Is there a general principle from which the polynomiality and divisibility by $\binom{n}{k}$ are obvious? Is there a combinatorial interpretation for the remaining term after dividing by $\binom{n}{k}$?